# "Одностайне рішення" чи "Одноголосне рішення"?

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами

В СУМі є слово "[одностайний](http://sum.in.ua/s/odnostajnyj)" та "[одноголосний](http://sum.in.ua/s/odnogholosnyj)" (причому одноголосний - це одностайно схвалений).

Однак, [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%80%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) подає лише "Одностайне рішення". Про такий же варіант пишуть на форумі [Словник.ua](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2548.html):

> Ходить пошесть Україною. Рішення, що ухвалюються "одностайно",
>   називають рішеннями, що ухвалюються "одноголосно". "Одноголосно" - це
>   щось, що діється одним голосом, і лише одним. У разі, якщо всі
>   присутні згодні з якоюсь пропозицією, вони це роблять багатьма
>   голосами, але в унісон, тобто вони роблять це "одностайно". Якщо у
>   такому контексті вживати термін "одноголосно", це означатиме, що
>   рішення колективного органу прийнято волюнтаристськи одним чиїмсь
>   голосом. Тобто, це буде спотворенням сенсу.
>
> Для питомо російськомовних людей різниці межи тими двома словами
>   немає, адже в російській мові "одноголосно" має і те значення, й інше.
>   Але ж ми розмовляємо українською і маємо застосовувати терміни
>   властиві нашій мові та у значеннях, що є притаманними нашій мові, а не
>   чужинським мовам.

І тут же наводиться невеликий контраргумент:

> Я згоден, що слову одностайно таки варто надавати перевагу над
>   одноголосно. Хоча б тому, що вчувається близькість другого до
>   російського (а чи й церковнослов’янського?) слова единогласно. Але
>   ніяк не можу погодитися з вашим трактуванням. Чи ви забули
>   фразеологізм в один голос, що його вельми часто вживали наші класики й
>   уживають теперішні письменники та й не тільки?

А крім того контраргументом буде те, що навіть коло визначення слова "одноглосний" із СУМу стоїть (про рішення, ухвалу і тд.).

Бачимо, що ці слова можуть бути [синонімами](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) із значенням "Який виражає, виявляє спільну волю". І там же коло слова "одноголосний" пише:

> при голосуванні - прийнятий усіма присутніми

[Словник синонімів Полюги](http://slovopedia.org.ua/31/53406/28769.html) також подає їх як синоніми.

В Інтернеті зустрічаються як один, так і інший варіанти. То як бути і якому із них надавати перевагу? Чи вони обоє вірні?

Answer (score 8):

Рішення приймають одностайно .
Приклади з українських новин:
«Рішення про воєнний стан не буде одностайним». Еспресо.TV

«Парафіяни одностайно проголосували за рішення щодо переходу до Православної церкви України» Ukr. Press.info

ОДНОГОЛО́СНО. Присл. до одноголосний. Китайська народна музика.. одноголосна. Одноголосно співає хор, одноголосно грає оркестр народних інструментів (Народна творчість та етнографія, 4, 1962, 110); Головою земельної комісії майже одноголосно обрали Тимофія Горицвіта (Михайло Стельмах, II, 1962, 20).
Словник української мови

Comment: Але ж _[одноголосний](http://sum.in.ua/s/odnogholosnyj)_ у «Словнику української мови», на який Ви посилаєтеся, якраз має два значення: «який виконується в один голос» і «одностайний»

Comment: Мабуть семантична різниця така сама як між російськими `единодушно` та `единогласно`. Якщо провести голосування, то `одностайність` отримує документальне підтвердження і стає `одноголосністю`